# Can you use Spring Boot with a camelLoadListener?

Tags: routes, apache-camel, messaging, spring-boot

The Camel website says that you need to define the listener in the web.xml, but a spring boot app doesn't have a web.xml. I only need to pick up one message from the browser so I would like to use the contextloadlistener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure if you look in more detail Camel will have support for Servlet 3 containers as well (and Java APIs). But you can use Spring Boot with a web.xml if you insist (obviously it has to be a war file). Example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-traditional/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml